# OGR_G_ForceToPolygon() doesn't produce polygon - GDAL C API

Tags: gdal, polygon, geometry, convert, ogr

Using the C APIs for GDAL 2.2.2 (within Swift app) I have a very simple `OGRGeometryRefH` that is a `wkbLineString`.

I'm creating the `wkbLineString` and attempting to convert it to a `wkbPolygon` geometry by doing:

```
let lineStringGeom = OGR_G_CreateGeometry(wkbLineString)
print("lineStringGeom type:  \(OGR_G_GetGeometryType(lineStringGeom).rawValue)")
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 10, 10)
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 50, 50)
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 50, 10)
let polygonGeometry = OGR_G_ForceToPolygon(lineStringGeom)
print("polygonGeometry type:  \(OGR_G_GetGeometryType(polygonGeometry).rawValue)")
```

But the resulting geometry is still a `wkbLineString`.  I get the output:

```
lineStringGeom type:  2
polygonGeometry type:  2
```

I know that the documentation says that it will only "try" to force the conversion to occur, but I would expect this particular conversion to succeed, as the `wkbLineString` is a very simple geometry - just a few coordinate pairs and not a multi-geometry.

Why does this not work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it's simply because the line string isn't 'closed'.  I had erroneously assumed that "forcing" to polygon would close the geometry if necessary.

Closing it manually, by adding an end point the same as the start point works.  Eg, this now works:

```
let lineStringGeom = OGR_G_CreateGeometry(wkbLineString)
print("lineStringGeom type:  \(OGR_G_GetGeometryType(lineStringGeom).rawValue)")
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 10, 10)
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 10, 50)
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 50, 50)
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 50, 10)
OGR_G_AddPoint_2D(lineStringGeom, 10, 10)
let polygonGeometry = OGR_G_ForceToPolygon(lineStringGeom)
print("polygonGeometry type:  \(OGR_G_GetGeometryType(polygonGeometry).rawValue)")
```

This now produced the output:

```
lineStringGeom type:  2
polygonGeometry type:  3
```

It's unfortunate that `OGR_G_CloseRings(geom)` cannot be used on a LineString geometry, however, this is fairly easy to accomplish manually (add a new point to the end with the coordinates of the first point).